# "Contact us" form submission best practice

Tags: contact-us

As a user, when I submit a "Contact us" form with [valid] info, should the page response show in the form (clear the form and show some "We have received your message" type of success message, either at the top or bottom of the form, or should they simply be redirected to another page showing the success message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directed to a new page. Clearing the form is troublesome because it lets the user refill it out, even though there's a message saying it's been received. Redirect moves them away and is a clearer state change for a user to understand.

Answer (score 1):

There are two good directions that I can think of:

**A. Replace form with a friendly success section**

Rather than redirect entirely, I'd recommend only replacing the form with a success message. That should prevent the user from getting disoriented and would allow them to interact with other elements on the page if there are any.

There should be a "Submit another message" button under the success message, in case the user wants to write again.

As a nice-to-have, think about including an illustration as part of this success section, to add a feeling of delight to the interaction. Bonus points for a subtle animation in the illustration. People generally remember the best and worst points in an interaction, and they're also likelier to remember the start and the end of one, so a charming experience at the end of an interaction goes a long way.

**B. Clear the form and show a temporary success message**

I've never seen this approach be a problem for users. On the contrary, it seems to meet their expectations. If you go with this approach, be sure that:

- that it animates in so that it's noticed
- the success message stays on long enough to be noticed (I use 3.5 s)
- it's visible no matter the size of the window (you can animate the "Submit" button for this or use a bottom toast)

While potentially not as charming as the first approach, this approach tends to be a lot simpler to implement.

---

No matter which direction you go with, be sure to send the user **an e-mail confirming that his message was received**. As a nice-to-have, it's nice to confirm that their message will be read and mention whether the user should expect a reply and, if so, how long it might take.