# Why does the "Thank you for contacting us" page still include the contact form?

Tags: feedback, confirmation

After submitting a subscription or contact page, the user is typically presented with the same form with one change: an often small statement saying "Thank you for your response." Why would the "Thank you for subscribing" page still include the subscription form? It makes me think I'm supposed to fill it out again. Wouldn't it be better to replace the form with the confirmation message? But this anti-pattern is so common, it makes me assume it has supporters in the UX community.

Related:
["Contact us" form submission best practice](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/120199/contact-us-form-submission-best-practice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is going to be a mix of Business Understanding and UX, feel free to query / comment accordingly.

Answer -
A subscription or contact us page is the first line of contact with the customer online for many businesses. Mostly the submitted form includes information like phone number / email id etc. which helps the organisation to reach out back to the customer. Hence it is a good practice to show back the data entered by the user, just in case if the user has mis-entered some information he should be allowed to correct it again.

Specifically to your doubt -

1. It might be better to show all fields non-editable with the user's data.
2. Add a message - "The following data was submitted by you, we will reach out to you on your provided contact details"
3. Give a "Edit" button which allows to resubmit the info with minor edits.

---

An Example -
Your designed contact page is being used by ABC.corp.
User X is requesting for quotations from ABC and its competitors and has queried for an order of 1000 units of whatever ABC produces, but since he is doing this on 5 different sites in a hurry he swaps 2 digits of his phone number.
Loss of business and negative reviews to a business matter a lot and also its a good practice in UX terms.